# SQL server DEFAULT DATEFORMAT to Neutral language

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm wondering if anybody knows of any setting you can set IN SQL SERVER.

so it accepts any date format(dmy,ymd,mdy,ect.)[image]
I know changing the Languages changes the format, but i need to know if there is any other way to make it a global accepting format.

Comment: something like UserLanguage

Comment: What you mean **global accepting format**? US use _mdy_, UK use _dmy_. For example, _10112016_, SQL accept this, but you can't tell this is 10 Nov or Oct 11.

Comment: Yea, so basically i want to use the USERs language as my language...or have some setting that accepts all formats.

Comment: Instead of change the SQL server setting, you should change your input to [ISO 8601](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977(v=sql.90).aspx) or _YYYYMMDD_

Comment: I agree with Alex's comment, stick to ANSI standard and proper date/datetime data types, do not rely on the local language settings.